# Powershell Start-Process does not start .exe properly

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a program that I want to start with a PowerShell script.

When double-clicking on the program exe in Windows Explorer it starts some process that checks whether the program is latest version and checks for the existance of a couple of updater files.

If the version is current, the program login form starts, otherwise first it gets updated (I recon it starts the updaters) and then the logon form opens.

When I use "Start-Process" it just gives me an error message that the updater files are missing (they aren't). If I try to start it by just pasting the exe's full path and hitting ENTER - the same thing happens.

I runs correctly, however, if I first `cd` into the directory of the exe and then either call the exe like `.\program.exe` or use `start-process .\program.exe`.

What causes this difference in behaviour?

Comment: Does it is specific to PowerShell? What if you use `CMD` instead? Or if you create shortcut to `.exe` file and then change working directory property of that shortcut? Maybe program just poorly written and do not acknowledge the fact that working directory is not always the directory where `.exe` file reside.

Comment: What is the PowerShell version?

Comment: @tukan, I thought it was 4, but it turns out it's 2. I'll update to 4, now.

Comment: @PetSerAl, oh, so that's the difference? `Start-Process` tells the exe the working directory is whatever the pwd is when it's invoked? That would explain why it isn't working - most probably the program is looking for the files in "CurrentWorkingDirectory".

Comment: @J.Doe *`Start-Process` tells the exe the working directory is whatever the pwd is when it's invoked?* Yes, this is default behavior: unless otherwise specified, child process inherit current working directory from its parent. `Start-Process -WorkingDirectory`

Comment: @PetSerAl, how do I tell it not to do that?